# What is the expected size of a Hello World dotnet binary? (And is 2kB achievable?)

Tags: c#, compilation, compiler-optimization, filesize

I was requested to send a compiled .exe file. The first time I sent it I made the mistake of including the whole dotnet runtime in the exe (compiler options: `/p:PublishSingleFile=true` and `--self-contained=true` - my thinking was, *let's make sure the file runs of the recipient's computer no matter if they have the runtime installed*), so the file was 60MB large and the recipient rejected it, saying that they do not need the whole runtime and that a typical dotnet executable binary should be no more than 2kB in size.

...2kB??

I tried a Hello World console app: around 170 kb (of course not self contained).

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it expected that a Hello World app be that large?

I compile it with `dotnet publish` - should I compile this in another way? Language is C# and this is required.

Or did the recipient make a typo? Maybe he meant 2**M**B and not kB?

As far as I'm aware I'm using dot net core 3.1.

Comment: Leaving out PDB and manifest and turning off Auto-Serialization, I can get a Hello World console app down to 4kb (targeting .Net 4.8).

Comment: @Filburt How to turn off autoserialization? Neither this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish nor this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference seems to mention such a thing as autoserialization. Tried googling but also no luck

Comment: If you are targeting core 3.1 this doesn't seem to make that much of a difference: My .exe ended up with 167kb. You can control automatic creation of a Serialization Assembly on the *Build* tab of your project settings - right at the bottom: *"Generate serialization assembly"*.